# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am playing around with Bootstrap and trying out the tooltips but they don't seem to work. I got the following simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tooltip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Which looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/a1d844593410ac2c7c13546182317579.png

Could someone please point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery to be loaded. From the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included):

> **jQuery required**
>   Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

You should see an error in your browser console telling you:

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Add this line before the Bootstrap Javascript file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It worked but I hade to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` any reason to that?

Comment: @DavidG You have the wrong link. Looks like you confused jQuery with jQuery UI.